# Optimize the performance of SQL query

Tags: sql

I need to fetch all the ID's from certain tables in between two timestamps

```
select Distinct PK1 from(
SELECT A.PK1 
FROM  T1 A , T2 B, T3 C, T4 D 
WHERE TO_CHAR(A.DATE1,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS' )>= '2016-06-01 00:00:00' 
AND TO_CHAR(A.DATE1,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS' ) <= '2016-06-02 00:00:00' and a.PK2 is not null 
AND A.PK2=B.PK2 AND B.PK3 IS NOT NULL AND B.PK3=C.PK3 AND C.PK4 IS NOT NULL 
AND C.PK4=D.PK4 AND D.PK5 IS NOT NULL 
union

SELECT A.PK1
FROM  T1 a, T2 B , T3 C, T4 D
WHERE TO_CHAR(A.DATE2,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS' )>= '2016-06-01 00:00:00'
AND TO_CHAR(A.DATE2,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS' )  <='2016-06-02 00:00:00'  and a.PK2 is not null 
AND A.PK2=B.PK2 AND B.PK3 IS NOT NULL AND B.PK3=C.PK3 AND C.PK4 IS NOT NULL 
AND C.PK4=D.PK4 AND D.PK5 IS NOT NULL 
UNION
select A.PK1
from  T11 A, T1 B , T2 C, T3 D, T4 E  WHERE 
TO_CHAR(A.DATE1,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')>='2016-06-01 00:00:00'
AND TO_CHAR(A.DATE1,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')<='2016-06-02 00:00:00' 
AND A.PK1=B.PK1 AND B.PK2 IS 
NOT NULL AND B.PK2=C.PK2 AND C.PK3 IS NOT NULL AND C.PK3=D.PK3 AND D.PK4 IS NOT NULL
AND D.PK4=E.PK4 AND E.PK5 IS NOT NULL  
UNION

select A.PK1
from  T15 A , T1 B, T2 C, T3 D, T4 E WHERE 
TO_CHAR(A.DATE1,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')>='2016-06-01 00:00:00'  
AND TO_CHAR(A.DATE1,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')  <='2016-06-02 00:00:00'  
AND A.PK1=B.PK1 AND B.PK2 IS NOT NULL 
AND B.PK2=C.PK2 AND C.PK3 IS NOT NULL AND C.PK3=D.PK3 AND D.PK4 IS NOT NULL 
AND D.PK4=E.PK4 AND E.PK5 IS NOT NULL 

UNION

select A.PK1 
from  T12 a, T6 b, T1 C, T2 D, T3 E, T4 F WHERE 
TO_CHAR(b.DATE1,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')>='2016-06-01 00:00:00'
AND TO_CHAR(b.DATE1,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')  <='2016-06-02 00:00:00' and A.PK6=b.PK6 AND A.PK1=C.PK1 AND 
  C.PK2 IS NOT NULL AND C.PK2=D.PK2 AND D.PK3 IS NOT NULL AND D.PK3=E.PK3
  AND E.PK4 IS NOT NULL AND E.PK4=F.PK4 AND F.PK5 IS NOT NULL

UNION

select A.PK1 
from  T13 A, T7 b, T1 C, T2 D, T3 E, T4 F WHERE 
TO_CHAR(b.DATE1,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')>='2016-06-01 00:00:00'
AND TO_CHAR(b.DATE1,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')  <='2016-06-02 00:00:00'

and A.PK7=b.PK7 AND A.PK1=C.PK1 AND 
  C.PK2 IS NOT NULL AND C.PK2=D.PK2 AND D.PK3 IS NOT NULL AND D.PK3=E.PK3
  AND E.PK4 IS NOT NULL AND E.PK4=F.PK4 AND F.PK5 IS NOT NULL


UNION

select A.PK1 
from  T13 A, T7 b, T1 C, T2 D, T3 E, T4 F WHERE 
TO_CHAR(b.DATE2,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')>='2016-06-01 00:00:00'
AND TO_CHAR(b.DATE2,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')  <='2016-06-02 00:00:00'

and A.PK7=b.PK7 AND A.PK1=C.PK1 AND 
  C.PK2 IS NOT NULL AND C.PK2=D.PK2 AND D.PK3 IS NOT NULL AND D.PK3=E.PK3
  AND E.PK4 IS NOT NULL AND E.PK4=F.PK4 AND F.PK5 IS NOT NULL

UNION

select A.PK1 
from  T13 A, T7 b, T1 C, T2 D, T3 E, T4 F WHERE 
TO_CHAR(b.DATE3,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')>='2016-06-01 00:00:00'
AND TO_CHAR(b.DATE3,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')  <='2016-06-02 00:00:00'

and A.PK7=b.PK7 AND A.PK1=C.PK1 AND 
  C.PK2 IS NOT NULL AND C.PK2=D.PK2 AND D.PK3 IS NOT NULL AND D.PK3=E.PK3
  AND E.PK4 IS NOT NULL AND E.PK4=F.PK4 AND F.PK5 IS NOT NULL

UNION
select A.PK1 
from  T14 a, T8 b, T1 C, T2 D, T3 E,
 T4 F WHERE 
TO_CHAR(b.DATE1,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')>='2016-06-01 00:00:00'
AND TO_CHAR(b.DATE1,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')  <='2016-06-02 00:00:00' and A.PK8=b.PK8 AND A.PK1=C.PK1 AND 
  C.PK2 IS NOT NULL AND C.PK2=D.PK2 AND D.PK3 IS NOT NULL
  AND D.PK3=E.PK3
  AND E.PK4 IS NOT NULL AND E.PK4=F.PK4 AND F.PK5 IS NOT NULL

 )
```

My question is how can I optimize the query for better performance.

Comment: I have also attached the table structure

Comment: First you should consider using `JOIN` instead of old SQL-89 ANSI syntax

Answer (score 2):

You are converting your dates to chars. If you do the compares using the datetype date, and add indexes to the date columns your performance will probably increase. The conversions are really bad for performance and result in table scans.

Comment: You can use OR, but that will probably decrease your performance. Unions give you probably the best performance, look at your execution plan to see what columns need a index. We are not going to dig into your complex where statements and see if they can be simplified, the naming is not very intuitive and we can't really understand what you are functionally try to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

Using to_char here converts date in every row to characterset, then compares it to value on right side. At the top of your code, convert value on right hand side to datetime and compare that to column of date type directly. That will make it faster.

Also, you can check out estimated query execution path, and minimize cost of individual steps.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs